# How to filter nested ng-repeat by parent id?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-filter

I have an array

```
lists = [{"id":"1234"},{"id":"5423"},{"id":"65342"}]
```

And array with contents:

```
contents = [{"id":"1","listId":"1234"},{"id":"2","listId":"5423"}]
```

How can I filter ng-repeat for "contents" inside ng-repeat for "lists" and filter "contents" by content.listID equal list.id?

Comment: make a plunker and show the problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
ng-repeat="e in contents | filter: {listId: lists.id}"
```

You will have to parent id to child array and child array will be filtered for that parent id. [plnk](http://plnkr.co/edit/7KlAX1XmwdUyUMnk6XlJ?p=preview) for similar example.

Regards.

Answer (score 2):

You should probably be doing this mapping in the controller rather than in the view, but the below example will show you how to do it.

```js
(function() {
  'use strict';

  angular
    .module('exampleApp', [])
    .controller('ExampleController', ExampleController);

  function ExampleController() {
    var vm = this;
    vm.lists = [{
      "id": "1234"
    }, {
      "id": "5423"
    }, {
      "id": "65342"
    }]
    vm.contents = [{
      "id": "1",
      "listId": "1234"
    }, {
      "id": "2",
      "listId": "5423"
    }]
  }
  ExampleController.$inject = [];
})();
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app='exampleApp'>

<head>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.5.5/angular.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body ng-controller="ExampleController as vm">
  <div ng-repeat="item in vm.lists">
    <p ng-repeat="content in vm.contents | filter:{ listId: item.id }">Content ID: {{content.id}} Lists ID: {{item.id}}</p>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```